# Get individual values of node in android

Tags: android, xpath

Here, I'm parsing xml file using xpath successfully. But the output is not as I expected. What I'm doing here is parsing .xml into list view. List view shows parsed data but not in proper way. Below is my .xml file,

```
<main>
       <category id="Love">
                <item>Love u</item>
                <item>Love u too</item>

        </category>

          <category id="Birthday">
                <item>Happy Bday</item>
                <item>Many Many Happy</item>
                <item>Have a blast</item>
        </category>
</main>
```

Below is my code which gives output.

```
InputSource inputSrc = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.detail));
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String expression = "//main/category[@id=" + "'" + detail + "'" +  "]";
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSrc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        // if node found
        if(nodes != null && nodes.getLength() > 0) {
            mDetail.clear();
            data.clear();
            int len = nodes.getLength();
            for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {

                Node node = nodes.item(i);
                mDetail.add(node.getTextContent());

                Toast.makeText(this, node.getNodeValue(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        else
        {
             Toast.makeText(this, "No Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             mDetail.clear();
        }
```

But here I'm not getting output in proper manner. List view shows data but in single row which is shown in below image.

[image]

I want data in indib=vidual row of list view. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you elaborate what that means: "I want data in indib=vidual row of list view."? and or what exactly is the question...

Comment: actually here I'm getting all the data in single row of listview as shown in figure. I want each data in each row of listview.

Comment: Well, we will need to see your list view/ list adaptor code in order to help. Consider pasting the relevant portions of the code.

Comment: I can definitely see two rows in the figure, not only one. Or do you mean two _columns_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String expression = "//main/category[@id=" + "'" + detail + "'" +  "]"  + "/item";
```

change your expression...